# Slicing a 2D array for multiple times to get a 3D array in NumPy

Tags: numpy, numpy-slicing

Given a 2D array:

```
samples = np.array(
              [
                  [1, 2, 3, 4],
                  [5, 6, 7, 8],
                  [9, 10, 11, 12],
                  [13, 14, 15, 16]
              ]
          )
```

and two 2D arrays (slices) of shape (n, 2):

```
slices_x = np.array(
               [
                   [0,2],
                   [1,3]
               ]
           )

slices_y = np.array(
               [
                   [1,3],
                   [0,2]
               ]
           )
```

I want to slice the array like the following:

```
result = []
for slice_x, slice_y in zip(slices_x, slices_y):
    result.append(samples[slice_x[0]:slice_x[1], slice_y[0]:slice_y[1]])
result = np.stack(result)
```

which in this case will get the result (of shape (2,2,2)):

```
[
    [
        [2, 3],
        [6, 7]
    ],
    [
        [5, 6],
        [9, 10]
    ]
]
```

In other words, `result[i]` is given by

```
samples[slice_x[i][0]:slice_x[i][1], slice_y[i][0]:slice_y[i][1]]
```

Are there any efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: Hi welkcome to stackoverflow. Thank you for a well structured question, however your code currently doesn't run. `indices_x` is missing a `,`. Also `slices_x` and `slices_y` are undefined. Please edit the code for the best responses. Also, I assume samples should be a numpy array.

Comment: @Seven - your slices have the property that they are all length 2, which makes this a special case, both because of the value 2 and because they're always the same. Is that representative?